# Opening multiple images in one window, and opening multiple such type of windows

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to html and javascript. I am working on a web based UI where I have a lot of data to show on a web page. I am showing it in table. Now for each row I have 2 images to display. I want to create one link in each row which opens a new window and show both the images. And also when I click on other links in other rows they should also open with the previous window already open.

Here is what I am doing:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$total_images;$i++){
    <tr><td><a href=\"JavaScript:newPopup('/var/www/html/images/imga$i.png','/var/www/html/images/imgb$i.png');\">Open Images with Link $i</a><td></tr>
}
```

and here is the **javascript**

```
function newPopup(url1,url2) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url1,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    popupWindow = window.open(url2,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
```

The problem I am having is that this is opening only the second image not both images and I have to close the previous window for opening a new one.

Please tell me what mistake I am doing or what modifications I need to do in code to resolve both problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `popUpWindow` as the reference for both.

That means the 2nd call to `window.open` will not open a new window, but will use the already existing one.

Give them different refences, for example...

```
function newPopup(url1,url2) {
  popupWindow1 = window.open(url1,'popUpWindow1',...);
  popupWindow2 = window.open(url2,'popUpWindow2',...);
}
```

---

In addition, due to comments by the OP, if you **always** want a new window then use `_blank` as a reference...

```
window.open(url1,'_blank',...);
```

Comment: Then you will have to write a page that accepts two parameters (probably via query string) and then display those images in there. Browsers cannot display two images at the same time when navigating directly to the image

Comment: Thanks .. and the second problem in which I have to close previous window for opening next. Actually I have to compare images from various rows so they need to be open at same time but here I have to close the previous one, what to do about it ??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your requirement. If you do a `window.open` with a reference that is the same as a window that has already been opened, then the contents will be replaced with the new URL.  I don't understand the "compare images" part

Comment: yeah actually I have to open new window whenever I click on a link I dont want the images to come in same window. A new window for each image.

Comment: In that case, use `_blank`... `window.open(url1,'_blank',...);` That will create a new window every time

Comment: You dont need to set the url to the newly window. instead write the contents you want into a window WITHOUT an url

Answer (score 0):

You can open both urls in one window as easy as:

```
 function newPopup(url1,url2){  
                    var contents = '<img src="' + url1+ '"></img>' + '<img src="' + url2+ '"></img>' ;
                    var previewWindow = window.open('','Preview','','');
                    previewWindow.document.body.innerHTML = contents;
                }
```

Comment: `<img></img>` isn't quite correct, as `<img/>` cannot contain anything, and is therefore a self-closing tag.

Comment: well..you are right. There won't ever be a content but this is a equivalent writing to <img/>. By the way to my opinion <tag/> is only a shortcut for <tag></tag>